# How to move my marker position one location to another location based upon coordinates in google map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

Currently i am making app like uber here i want show driver moving location on user map. Already i have driver coordinates based on these coordinates how to move marker on my map.

Ex:Currently i am making two apps one is user end and another one driver end.
if user want to travel from one location to another location. At that time user should request for specific driver.

If Driver accept that request means in User side i am getting Driver current location latitude & Longitude, But the thing is i need to show that Driver Car (Custom Image) image on GoogleMaps with moving animation

If any one know. Please help me out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. To Show Custom Image on Marker:

```
    marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,
                                                lng);
    [marker setIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:kMarkerImage]];
    marker.map = self.mapView_;
```

> 2. To make Moving Animation

Your have to Make `HTTP` request continuously `(1-2 sec delay in each call)` if you are getting Driver Co-Ordinates.

If you are using User Co-ordinates then also you have to do same step.

Then You have to first `Clear` the Map else you will get `multiple` marker added on it. and then Add new Markers with NewCordinates.

```
 [self.mapView_ clear];
```

Comment: This is not the feasible solution for this question? . What i want is In uber application continuously driver cab shold move as per driver driving location  in USER side application. I am also look forward same

Comment: yes bro...they are able to do so because they continuosuly fetch drivers location and upload to server and in user ends their is api call which frequently checks the driver positions...

Answer (score 0):

Take two variables of type CLLocationCoordinate2D:

```
Last_Location = last locaiton of your marker
Current_Location = current location of marker
```

initially Last_Location and Current_Location will be same after getting first location update, write following code:

```
    let p1: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(Last_Location)
    let p2: MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(Current_Location)
    let dist: CLLocationDistance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(p1, p2)
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(6.0)
    your_marker.position = Last_Location
    your_marker.position = Current_Location
    CATransaction.commit()

    Last_Location = Current_Location
```

Call above line of code after getting new location update. Hope this will help :-)